# Problems extracting elements by class names with Selenium

Tags: selenium

From this page: https://www.realestate.com.kh/buy/, which looks like this in the inspector:

[image]

I'm trying to extract all elements of class `css-1uuzwjq eq4or9x0` into a list in order to click on the elements and further explore.

I have this code, in which I try to get the elements by their Xpath:

```
ads = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('css-1uuzwjq eq4or9x0')
for ad in ads:
    ad.click()
```

However, the list always ends up empty. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

class attribute holds multiple classes , each class is separated by space. In your case, 'css-1uuzwjq eq4or9x0' are two classes not one

you can find it as :#

- xpath

in xpath it validates the class attribute value is exactly the same

```
//*[@class="css-1uuzwjq eq4or9x0"]
```

- CSS

in css it checks for element that contains both the mentioned class, each class should be mentionedwith a dot

```
.css-1uuzwjq.eq4or9x0
```

if you want exact match , use the below locator as it checks the class attribute value to be exact

```
[class="css-1uuzwjq eq4or9x0"]
```

- using class locator

  browser.find_elements_by_class_name('css-1uuzwjq.eq4or9x0')

calss locator uses css locator under the  hood , so when you pass a class name, it just adds 'dot' in front of it . so to make it a valid locator pass all classes by replacing space with dot

Answer (score 2):

```
//div[@class='list']/div[./header[contains(@class,'featured')]]
```

I would use this xpath to obtain all the divs needed to search.

use  /div/header/a if you want the a tag to click.

So it would be

```
driver.get('https://www.realestate.com.kh/buy/')
hrefs=[x.get_attribute('href') for x in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='list']/div/header/a")]
print(hrefs)
for href in hrefs:
    driver.get(href)
```

Would retrieve all the hrefs to loop and will prevent using driver.back() and all the stale elements you will get.

I would not recommend getting by class name because they seem dynamic  also those are multiple class names which are grabbed by a css selector.

```
css-1uuzwjq eq4or9x0 -> .css-1uuzwjq.eq4or9x0
```